# Слайдер с несколькими изображениями

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Не могу найти похожий слайдер, может у кого-нибудь есть в закладках ссылочка на аналогичный готовый плагин? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по тебе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.js-carousel').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.slide {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="js-carousel">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/320x150"> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x150"> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x150"> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/420x150"> </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/350x150"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно использоват [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) в опциях ставите  `centerMode: true`

Comment: пробовал, с ним коряво получается из-за того что боковые должны быть разного размера, можно ставить им transform: scale(Number) но там, с анимацией тогда проблемы, она не плавная, а дергается заметно(

Comment: @СергейКозин, Все нормально работает и с разными размерами изображений, нужно просто добавить одно свойство.