# Как сделать аналогичный слайдер?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

подскажите как сделать такой слайдер [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

понимаю что сделан с помощью плагина Swiper но сделать такой не получается :( слайдер есть здесь https://mserj.ru/works/109/index.html

Comment: подобный вопрос вы уже задавали и вам ответили  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836758/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Слайдер с несколькими изображениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836758/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам слайдер так как хотели в предидущем ответе и тут.

Называетсья это прелесть **waterwheelCarousel** впервые использовал между прочим

Я добавил `prev` и `next` кнопки измените их на стрелки и будет то что вам надо

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var carousel = $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
    flankingItems: 3,
  });

  $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
    carousel.prev();
    return false
  });

  $('#next').bind('click', function () {
    carousel.next();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> this is jquery carousel</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="carousel">
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/1.jpg" id="item-1"/>
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/2.jpg" id="item-2"/>
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/3.jpg" id="item-3"/>
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/4.jpg" id="item-4"/>
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/5.jpg" id="item-5"/>
    <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Waterwheel-Carousel-Plugin/images/6.jpg" id="item-6"/>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
  <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>

</body>
</html>
```